# Get application name that executes specific stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I want to know the application name that executes a specific stored procedure. We have many applications and all have application name property inside the connection string.

Here I don't exactly know which application calling that stored procedure. I think we can get this by calling `APP_NAME()` but I don't know the exact query to get the correct application name.

```
SELECT APP_NAME()
```

Comment: That would be the query to get the name of the application for the current connection; **provided** the application has passed it's name in it's connection string. If not, then the information won't be available. If that is the case, you'll therefore need to ensure you change your application code to ensure the name of the application is included in the connection string. What about the above isn't working as you expect (apart from the prior caveat)?

Comment: You can try using SQL Server Profiler to capture the procedure call. It contains the application name info. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

The APP_NAME() is a built-in function to return the 'Application Name' token from the connection string used to set up the current session.

Here is a good article on setting up your connection string appropriately:
http://www.sqlerudition.com/using-a-meaningful-application-name-in-the-oledb-connection-string/

If you don't have control over the connection string, then you will need to use a combination of other session variables such as SESSION_USER() or @@SPID and possibly refer to the dmv called sys.dm_exec_sessions for a full record of what the server 'knows' about the connection.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Application Name already exist on connection string, just want to know how we can get the application name from sql server query that call sp.

Comment: you could let the profiler run filtered on `application name` for a while and then check the results

Answer (score 0):

If you want detailed information, i would suggest to use Extended Events by selecting `rpc_completed` event. [For detailed steps..](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/245285/185080)